# Obter Diretório Depois de Compilado JAVA

Tags: java, arquivo, algoritmo-de-busca

De antemão gostaria de dizer que já procurei em diversos links indicados aqui no stackoverflow e em outros sites também e ainda não consegui ajuda concreta (pode ser por erro meu também).

Preciso obter um `file` encontrado na pasta `res`, essa pasta `res` esta dentro da pasta do projeto (fora da pasta `src` para ficar mais claro).

Logo no meu programa eu consigo fazer o seguinte("enquanto no NetBeans")

```java
   public static void obter(){
       File f = new File("res\\file.txt");
   }
```

no metodo acima ele consegue ler enquanto estiver rodando no netbeans.
Fora do netBeans não.
Erro gerado fora do NetBeans:

```
res\file.txt (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)
```

Em outro lugar do meu código utilizo o código abaixo e também funciona no netBeans

```java
File f = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/file.txt").getFile());
```

no metodo acima mesmo sem especificar a pasta `res` ele ainda consegue encontrar enquanto estiver no netBeans. Porem fora do netBeans me retorna isso:

```
file:\C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TEST\dist\TEST.jar!\file.txt (A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diretório ou do rótulo do volume está incorreta)
```

Como obter esse `file.txt` da pasta `res` mesmo que eu compile o código e passe pra qualquer computador?

PS: se não deixei claro por favor me avise e tento melhorar minha pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu gostaria de agradecer ao [Rafael Guasselli](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/161388/rafael-guasselli) pela ajuda, eu gostaria que ele estivesse corrigido a resposta para eu poder aprovar e deixar mais claro para as futuras pessoas que estivessem com o mesmo problema.

## Segue a resposta:

Após compilado o projeto no NetBeans ele gera uma pasta `dist` e lá contém os arquivos necessários para roda-lo. Logo se seu projeto precisa acessar alguma outra pasta deve-se colocar lá também após compilado.

## No exemplo abaixo precisamos encontrar a pasta `res`.

Ex: digamos que a pasta `res` está dentro da `src`....
  Então após compilado, vou até a pasta `dist` e crio uma pasta `src` e colo a pasta `res` lá dentro.

Caso a pasta `res` esteja fora da `src` então após compilado é só copia-la para a pasta `dist`.

## Isso serve também para as `lib` que costumam dar problema na hora de distribuir a aplicação.

Para que suas libs vá junto com o projeto, basta criar uma pasta chamada `lib`
lá dentro do seu projeto (fora da `src`).

Ex: `C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MeuProjeto\` (aqui eu crio a pasta `lib` e colo todas as libs que preciso). (Sim! Colo)

Logo após no NetBeans vou em adicionar Biblioteca >> add JAR/Folder

Aqui encontro a pasta lib que criamos, e dentro dela selecionamos todas as libs que precisamos. NOTA: Deixe Absolute Path(Caminho Absoluto) marcado.

## Por que isso?

Após compilado o `.jar` já vai ter uma pasta chamado lib no mesmo local que ele. Lembram daquela pasta `lib` criada ao compilar la em `dist`? Então, assim você garante que o caminho que ele esta buscando é exatamente o que ele vai ter após compilado. Ou seja, `lib/"as bibliotecas que inclui"`

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir rodar o jar depois de compilado tu precisa levar o arquivo junto com ele.
Tu pode ou colocar o jar em uma pasta e dentro dessa pasta criar a pasta res de novo e colocar o arquivo la ou tu pode compilar abrir o .jar com o winrar e botar a pasta res dentro do .jar.

Comment: Caso eu abra o .jar compilado com o winrar e coloque a pasta res la dentro, com o getResourses eu consigo obter acesso ao res? ou simplismente posso criar o File com caminho "res/file.txt" ?

Comment: Na real eu viajei, a parte de botar dentro do jar não da certo foi mal.
mas ainda da pra fazer assim:
deixa o arquivo dentro de uma pasta res dentro da src pra pegar quando tu todar no netbeans.
e depois de compilar tu copia a src so com os arquivos pra mesma pasta que o jar estiver.
e dae tu usa o primeiro comando
File file = new File("src/res/arquivo.txt");

Comment: vou fazer um teste quando estiver com mais tempo, e vejo se vai funcionar, apesar que a pasta res esta na package folder do netbeans, ou seja, se eu colocar File file = new File("res/arquivo.txt") ele ja consegue encontrar, então se eu compilar e colocar somente a pasta res junto com o .jar ele conseguira achar somente fazendo isso certo?  em breve volto com mais resultados..

Comment: Da maneira que comentamos aqui nos comentarios funcionou, é só compilar e criar uma pasta src/res/ e colocar os arquivos la que funciona. mas caso eu não queira usar a pasta src e quiser usar diretamente a pasta res é só incluir ela no package folder do netbeanse depois de compilado incluir essa pasta res aonde esta o .jar, assim nao precisa da pasta src.. Se quiser editar sua resposta e colocar isso eu ja vou sinalizar como resposta. xD vlw